# Residual deviance difference between multinom() and vglm() function

Tags: maximum-likelihood, multinomial-distribution, deviance

I have used two functions `multinom()` in package nnet and `vglm()` in package (VGAM) to make a multinomial logistic regression.

```
# packages
require(nnet)
require(VGAM)
require(foreign)

# load data
gator <- read.table("https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EF059954D82A6592!1855&authkey=!AISIAhhB66eHDZ0&ithint=file%2ctxt",
  header = TRUE)

# fit model with multinom () function
fit.multinom <- multinom(cbind(Fish, Bird, Invertebrate, Reptile, Other) ~ Lake + Size,
  data = gator)

# fit model with vglm() function
fit.vglm <- vglm(cbind(Bird, Invertebrate, Reptile, Other, Fish) ~ Lake + Size,
  data = gator, family = multinomial)

# model summary
summary(fit.multinom)
summary(fit.vglm)
```

The coefficients obtained from these two models are similar. However, the residual deviance are by far different (540 and 52, respectively).

But, these above differences only observed for response variable in matrix form. When response variable is presented in single column, both approach gives the same residual deviance (359.96) and AIC (375.96).

```
# load data
ml <- read.dta("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsbdemo.dta")

# model construction
ml$prog2 <- relevel(ml$prog, ref = "academic")
test.multinom <- multinom(prog2 ~ ses + write, data = ml)
test.vglm <- vglm(prog2 ~ ses + write, data = ml, family="multinomial")

# model summary
summary(test.multinom)
summary(test.vglm)
```

Could you help me explain why they are different?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is just by a constant. The VGAM package takes the multinomial coefficients into account while the nnet package does not. Note that this does not affect the analysis of deviance or information criteria etc. The multinomial coefficients stay the same (for all models on this data set) - so they just cancel out when looking at differences in deviance or log-likelihood.

I illustrate this with the log-likelihood below. The difference is:

```
logLik(fit.vglm)
## [1] -74.42948
logLik(fit.multinom)
## 'log Lik.' -270.0401 (df=20)
logLik(fit.vglm) - logLik(fit.multinom)
## 'log Lik.' 195.6107 (df=20)
```

The `multinom` version can be easily computed by hand, based on the predicted log-probabilities `p` and observed frequencies `y` for each category and observation:

```
p <- predict(fit.multinom, type = "prob")
y <- model.response(model.frame(fit.multinom))
sum(log(p) * y)
## [1] -270.0401
```

The `vglm` version adds the logarithm of the multinomial coefficient $n_i! / (y_{i1}! \dots y_{i5}!)$. The log-factorial $\log(n!)$ can be easily computed in R by `lgamma(n + 1)`. Hence we can easily comput the log-coefficient for each observation and then sum up:

```
lcf <- apply(y, 1, function(x) lgamma(sum(x) + 1) - sum(lgamma(x + 1)))
sum(lcf)
## [1] 195.6107
```

This is exactly the difference between the log-likelihoods as computed by the two packages. And this shows up again in the deviances.

Comment: Thanks Achim for your answer. However, could you explain me why the difference in residual deviance and AIC are not observed when response variable is represented in single column?

Comment: If you expand the data to have just a single multinomial choice per row, then the multinomial coefficient becomes 1 and in logs that is zero.

Comment: Dear Achim. Because the deviance and AIC change when the data is reconstructed (e.g., from a matrix of choice to a single multinomial choice per row). Could you let me know how can we assess the model fit from the result of multinom function?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Why don't you just decide to use one data format (either aggregated matrix response or individual vector response) and one modeling function (either vglm or multinom) and simply use that throughout. Up to a constant the results are the same anyway.